# Want to put MySql limit on each where condition

Tags: mysql

I want to refine my MySql condition by putting limit on each parameter.

Current query

```
Select * from product 
where name like "%abc%" or name like "%xyz%" 
limit 50
```

I got result having 50 rows for both condition. Now I want to get result on the base of each like condition such as

```
Select * from product 
where name like "%abc%" 
limit 50


Select * from product 
where name like "%xyz%" 
limit 50
```

I want to wrap up both above queries in one where I got 50 records for first query and another 50 for next one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use UNION ALL

```
Select * from product 
where name like "%abc%" 
limit 50

UNION ALL

Select * from product 
where name like "%xyz%" 
limit 50
```

Comment: If I have above 1000 conditions what is the effect on data base if we are running 1000 select statements?   It will take same time as in combined condition (first statement of the question)?

Comment: @pritinarang:- By 1000 conditions do you mean you have 1000 conditions in where clause. If yes then it entirely depends on your tables structure and the size of your table. However if your table size is small then it will not impact much if you put it like 1000 select(*which seems quite strange as what you want with the 1000 select*)

Comment: Yes my problem is that I have to put many conditions in select statement because i want to fetch more than 5000 records. which is good enough when I am trying it in single query but I can't put limit there.

Comment: @pritinarang:- I don't think it is going to impact much if your table is properly created. Also if the table size is excessively huge then you can create index on columns. UNION ALL will not impact the performance much.

Comment: @pritinarang: UNION ALL may be not impacted much but name like '%xyz%' will not use index and will degrade performance, so either try to search name like 'xyz%' if possible for you else try to use full text search...but full text search is worked only with myisam till 5.5 and worked with innodb as well in mysql5.6.

Comment: I can use full index search but problem is same how I can put limit there for each condition?

Answer (score 0):

Try union

```
Select * from product 
where name like "%abc%" 
limit 50

union all

Select * 
from product 
where name like "%xyz%" 
limit 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Union Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp), then:

```
Select * from product 
where name like "%abc%" 
limit 50

UNION ALL

Select * from product 
where name like "%xyz%" 
limit 50
```

Comment: If I have above 1000 conditions what is the effect on data base if we are running 1000 select statements?   It will take same time as in combined condition ?

Comment: I am not sure but I believe it's the same than use combined condition because in the end its has an equal translation. But for sure everything depends of your database, I mean data sizes, amount of record, amount of columns and so on. Its new question may be another good question to put here on stack, maybe some DBA can answer you better and give you a better solution.