# How to get rows from same table with different conditions

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to get data from same table with different conditions. I am using sqlite in android studio.

```
**ID    Name       Role**
1   Emma       Manager
2   Olivia     Manager
3   Ava        Manager
4   Isabella   Sales officer
5   Sophia     Sales Officer
6   Charlotte  Sales Officer
7   Mia        Clerk
8   Amelia     Clerk
```

Assume this table, I have different types of roles and different numbers of persons in a role. I want to select 2 persons from each role.

```
Select * from employeeTable where role = 'Manager' LIMIT 2
Select * from employeeTable where role = 'Sales officer' LIMIT 2
Select * from employeeTable where role = 'Clerk' LIMIT 2
```

Simply I want to join the result of these three queries. 
Sorry if the childish question. And thanks in advance

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688057/want-to-put-mysql-limit-on-each-where-condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `row_number()` window function:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.role 
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by role) rn
  from employeeTable
) t
where t.rn <= 2
```

You can also define:

```
partition by role order by name
```

or:

```
partition by role order by id
```

instead of just:

```
partition by role
```

to get specific rows in the results.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bc6Yar8sS2W8iDTpRb6cJc/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | Name     | Role          |
| --- | -------- | ------------- |
| 7   | Mia      | Clerk         |
| 8   | Amelia   | Clerk         |
| 1   | Emma     | Manager       |
| 2   | Olivia   | Manager       |
| 4   | Isabella | Sales Officer |
| 5   | Sophia   | Sales Officer |
```

Comment: That's really great! it solved my problem. Now there is a little issue. This query gets static data i.e. always select first 2 from each category. What if I want to select random/dynamic data from each Role / category? I mean to say that it should not get first two every time i run a query. But it should select 1st,3rd or 2nd,3rd or 1st,2nd

Comment: You can change the WHERE clause to something like: `where t.rn in (1, 3)` to get 1st and 3d or `where t.rn between 2 and 4` to get 2nd, 3d and 4th.

Answer (score 0):

Try is query and check if working:

```
Select * from employeeTable where role = 'Manager' LIMIT 2
UNION ALL
Select * from employeeTable where role = 'Sales officer' LIMIT 2
UNION ALL
Select * from employeeTable where role = 'Clerk' LIMIT 2
```

Comment: You cannot use limit before union all..this query won't work...

Comment: `select * from ( select * from  employeeTable where role = 'Manager' LIMIT 2 ) UNION ALL ( select * from ... = 'Sales Officer' LIMIT 2 ) UNION ALL ( select * ... 'Clerk' LIMIT 2 ) ;` will work.